# git-upload-pack: command not found on windows but works on osx

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to clone a repo.  (GitLabs if it matters)

The command:
git clone user@machine.com:user/project

Works like a champ - from OS-X, but it blows chunks on a Windows with the error:
git-upload-pack: command not found on windows

Now, obviously, I've see the messages here that say I just need to add it to the path on the, Ah, Remote (which is CLEARLY configured correctly as I can clone just fine from OS-X, and this is a install of GitLabs right out of the box on a fresh VM.)

And I've seen messages that say that I need to add it to the path on the Local Windows machine.  Yeah, done that.  I can run it from both a command prompt or a git bash shell without any issues.  (run the git-upload-pack command)

And 'git --exec-path' comes back with 
C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core

Which, of course has the program in it.

And obviously, the program should be telling me which side is failing, but it isn't.  It seems to me that 'upload' would have to be on the gitlabs side because that is the side that is uploading stuff right?

I've also tried creating the git repo locally and attempting to attach it the remote, but it says I don't have a remote set, and gives me a command to execute that fails.

> **git push origin**
>   fatal: The current branch master
>   has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote
>   as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin master
> ```
>
> **git push --set-upstream origin master**
>    error: src
>   refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to
>   'User@system.com:remoteUser/project.git'

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE:   I had edited the ssh value that gitlabs gave as: 'git@...' which I mistook should be user@, by changing it back to 'git@machine.com:user/project' I was able to correctly clone the Repo.  And also, it came back (as one would hope) with 'disallowed command' if I tried the --upload-pack command line argument.

Comment: For the last part, you need to configure a remote named `origin`. Check out the `git remote add` command.

Answer (score 1):

The `git fetch-pack` command runs on the server delivering the clone to the client.

When you run `git clone` or `git fetch` on a client, you can—but should not have to—add an argument:

```
--upload-pack <path>
```

This passes the path through to the next layer, which is `git fetch-pack` running on the server.  So the error you are seeing suggests that when someone clones from OS X, whatever machine is running the Gitlab server runs `git fetch-pack` which successfully runs `git upload-pack`—perhaps because of the user's `$PATH`?<sup>1</sup>—while the same or another user from a Windows box, running `git clone`, causes the same Gitlab server to run `git fetch-pack` which fails to find `git upload-pack`.

That's as far as I can get diagnosing this issue with what you've said here.

As [Code-Apprentice said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895265/git-upload-pack-command-not-found-on-windows-but-works-on-osx#comment88790603_50895265), if you create a repository without using `git clone`, you should use `git remote add` to add a remote.  (The `git clone` command is, essentially, `git init` followed by `git remote add` followed by `git fetch`, plus a few other Git items sprinkled in in-between as needed; then at the end, `clone` does a `git checkout`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This, obviously, depends on what OS and software is on the server.

Comment: I am using the same user for both.  I have a different SSH Key, but both keys are attached to the same gitlab user.   I wouldn't think the path on the windows or Os-X machine should matter to the server.   Server is CentOs.  If it can find get-fetch-pack, isn't git-upload-pack in the same directory?   --upload-pack path is a horrible hack  (Client shouldn't know, or care, or even be able to change that  --upload-pack /tmp/badCode  - which causes badCode/git-upload-pack to run which wipes the directory where all the git repos are.    I would assume you would have to be be admin to run that!!)

Comment: Indeed, the client type and path should not matter on the server. (And I agree that `--upload-pack` is terrible too, I assume it's there as a workaround for some case someone hit early on, or for developers doing testing.) I'd suggest adding logging on the server (somehow—it's not clear *how* to make the server more verbose...). The update you made, switching to `git@...`, suggests that perhaps you were using `git@` on the Mac?

Comment: It is possible, I'd have to check to be sure.  (It should still be listed as a remote for the repo..)